# What are python extensions in diffrent operating systems?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python. I am using ubuntu for software development using python. Here python extension in ubuntu.

**ubuntu :**

```
.py
.pyc
```

**Windows:**

```
?
```

**Mac :**

```
?
```

and also please explain the extensions.

Comment: They are the same, why should they be any different?

Comment: Guys this is not a duplicate, the OP wants to know if there are any differences, and if there are any, then to name them.

Comment: The link I gave goes into detail on each file extension (covering the "please explain the extensions") and notes that there are separate files such as the .pyd/.pyw. Admittedly, it does not explicitly state that there aren't special Mac files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same. In both windows and mac, you have `.py` files and compiled `.pyc` files. They are the same on all operating systems.

You might also occasionally meet `.pyo`, which is the same as a `.pyc` but it has been optimized. What that means really is that all `assert` statements are removed (used in testing software).

However, `.pyd` is specifically for windows. You can learn more about it from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll).

### UPDATE

> There is also `.pyw` for `pythonw` programs on Windows - these do not generate a Windows console

-- From cdarke

Comment: There is also `.pyw` for `pythonw` programs on Windows - these do not generate a Windows console.

Comment: @cdarke Hey, thats something awesome to know, please feel free to edit my answer. I would feel honored.

Comment: awesome?  You are easily impressed. ;-)

Comment: @cdarke my defense is that I'm still learning :P

Comment: @cdarke Gave you credit for the update. Thanks for telling me about `.pyw` files.